# Moving Background Transition with Image using custom segue swift

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, uiviewcontroller, segue

[I want to get moving background animation like this.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F27848409%2Fcustom-segue-with-separate-moving-background&psig=AOvVaw3uk7bWBM2G2D1alZzP4UY9&ust=1582018785523000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCLC7qLGl2OcCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)

1.I have a problem regarding the transition of the view controllers .
I have attached the following link above for the transition which i want to perform for my view controllers . 
Thanks and regards ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the HERO pod for such transitions  . 
This is the pod for installing HERO

**pod 'Hero'**